# How to show only images (non video ads) in interstitial ads - admob

Tags: java, android, admob

I am creating audio playing android app, I want to show interstitial ads that shows only image/text instead of video as I don't want to pause audio playing (for a good UX).lter  Is there any way to filter out video interstitial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you monetize with Google Admob, then log in to your Admob account > navigate to Ad Units page > click the interstitial ad-unit from table > go to Advancd settings > click on edit icon of ad type section and uncheck the video option > remember to click save

You are good to go with interstitials without videos

Answer (score 3):

You have to configure individual adUnit in your admob dashboard.
[A picture showing options to optout video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIcll.png)